# how to use netbeans ide and wamp server together for php project

Tags: php, wampserver, netbeans-7.1

I have installed netbeans ide 7.1 and wamp server 2.0 ,
my question is how can i use netbeans ide for debuging and running php code.
what setting are required for this.

Comment: you can find everything you need at [Netbeans PHP learning trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html). If you have any specific questions I'll be happy to help. Netbeans is a very nice PHP Ide that I use everyday. If you are unfamiliar with building a LAMP stack on windows, I would suggest you check out [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/) as it will more completely setup the eviroment.

Comment: Get your solution here

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596438/how-to-use-netbeans-integration-with-wamp-2-2-21

Comment: How did this get 6K views in 3 min ?

Answer (score 4):

Follow steps on [this link](http://hassoon3.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/developing-php-with-netbeans-7-0-1-and-wamp2-2-server/). The author provides a simple step-by-step guide.

Successfully followed guide using NetBeans 7.4 + WAMP v2.4

**Note: Instead of clicking on the "General" tab within the Tools --> Options menu you will click on the "Debugging" tab to modify the port.