# how to use NetBeans integration with WAMP 2.2.21?

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp

I try to work with NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 and I have some problem with the setting.
I can not successfully run the debugger.
I don't want to use to Xdebug I have a WAMP and it works OK with eclipse since I have some error from eclipse related to OOP and form. I decide to install additional  debugger the NetBeans.
I read some tutorial on the web and it has not helped me allot.

1.I Don't  know how to define in NetBeans the file php.ini .
2.I Don't know what line to add to php.ini.

any help are Appreciated.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are You running the project from within the Netbeans IDE?

Comment: yes the project runs ok and I can see the resualt on the brwoser.but I can't to debug

Comment: In Your php.ini, do You have present the properties Netbeans needs? Those `xdebug.remote_XXX`...

Comment: I found http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug Built in php and apache
Get Xdebug Sources and Install
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
***********************but I have WAMP and where I should have to define the wamp path php.ini on netbeans

Comment: I guess it is enough to set the PHP 5 interpreter within netbeans: Netbeans -> Tools -> Options -> PHP tab -> General tab -> set the path to the PHP interpreter within Your WAMP installation - the php.ini will be found automatically...

Comment: Thanks I add this line PHP 5 interpreter: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.exe  before I posted and PHP Unit script:C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\phar.phar.bat

Comment: So is it working now? If so, I will close this comments into an answer to Your question so You can accept it :-)

Comment: Because the PHP interpreter is not the `phar.phar.bat` but `php.exe`... The right path should be `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.exe`...

Answer (score 0):

When you have  fresh install of Netbeans and Wamp, it's really not that hard to get debugging working. Here's what you do:

1. Click the wamp icon and choose PHP->php.ini.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the file and set/add the following settings:

   xdebug.remote_enable = on
   xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
   xdebug.remote_host = localhost
   xdebug.remote_port = 9000
3. Restart all services.
4. Start debugging.

If you still can't use the debugger, it could be because the firewall is blocking netbeans.